# Why my query causes in Cardinality violation error PDO/PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cardinality

I'm using PDO to generate the following query:

```
  INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Data) 
  VALUES ( 
    (:id_0, :data_0), (:id_1, :data_1), (:id_2, :data_2), 
    (:id_3, :data_3), (:id_4, :data_4), (:id_5, :data_5), 
    (:id_6, :data_6), (:id_7, :data_7), (:id_8, :data_8), 
    (:id_9, :data_9)  
  )
```

this query is generated inside a loop so i just got the `print_r($query);` part and pasted here.

Then in my PHP i have a loop that binds the parameters like this:

```
   $c = 0;
   foreach($data as $key=> $value)
   {
        $insert->bindValue(":id_{$c}", $key, DB::PARAM_INT);
        $insert->bindValue(":data_{$c}", $value, DB::PARAM_STR);
        $c++;
   }
```

i get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

My Table Definition looks like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE MyTable(
        ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
        Data TEXT
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

can anyone help me?

```
 $data - this just holds key - value pairs where key is integer and value
 is serialized array.
```

Comment: just holds $key => $value pairs, where $key is integer and $value is serialized array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the outer `()` from your `VALUES` clause.  A multi-row `VALUES` clause is not `()` enclosed, but each comma-separated row group is `()` enclosed as in `VALUES (1,2,3),(3,2,1),(1,2,3)`.  By enclosing the whole row list, MySQL must be misinterpreting the outer `()` as the start of an expression whose result would be the first column.

```
VALUES /* no ( here... */
    (:id_0, :data_0), (:id_1, :data_1), (:id_2, :data_2), 
    (:id_3, :data_3), (:id_4, :data_4), (:id_5, :data_5), 
    (:id_6, :data_6), (:id_7, :data_7), (:id_8, :data_8), 
    (:id_9, :data_9)  
/* no ) here... */
```

Comment: Good catch. This is an example of why I prefer the `INSERT INTO mytable SET :id_0 = :data_0, :id_1 = : data_1, etc`